# Is the Image.getSize() function crashing my app?

Tags: javascript, react-native

My code looks something like the following

```
const [width, setWidth] = useState('');
const [height, setHeight] = useState('');
Image.getSize(link, (w, h) => {
  setWidth(w);
  setHeight(h);
})
return (
  <View>
    <ImageZoom
      cropWidth={dev_width}
      cropHeight={dev_height}
      imageWidth={width}
      imageHeight={height}
      enableCenterFocus={false}
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center'
      }}
    >
      <Image
        source={{uri: link}}
        style={{
          width: 4/5 * dev_width,
          aspectRatio: 0.3,
          resizeMode: "contain",
          alignSelf:'center'
        }}
      />
    </ImageZoom>
  </View>
)
```

What its supposed to do - Display a full-sized, zoomable, pannable image

What it does - It just crashes the app entirely with no error code.

My experience level and what I tried doing -
I've been learning react-native for barely a month so I have no idea what i'm doing wrong. I tried reading the documentations but nothing's helping. Google search results doesn't come up with anything relevant to my problem and I am at my wits' end. Can anyone help?

Comment: For one, you should wrap the `Image.getSize()` invocation in an `useEffect()` invocation (since it causes a side effect). Otherwise it would be run every time the component is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial states of both width and height were supposed to be 0 and not empty strings. Carelessness on my part. `Image.getSize()` should also be wrapped in `useEffect()` invocation.

```
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    Image.getSize(link, (w, h) => {
      setWidth(w)
      setHeight(h)
    })
  }, [])
```